# how are multiple console objects instantiated?

Tags: java, console, terminal, telnet, java-io

What's the general approach, or a tutorial, to spawning and interfacing with multiple console's?  Which API is generally used?  Hopefully it's in Java SE.  Do you use `java.io.Console`? Maybe `java.lang.Process`?

If so, would pseudo-code be something like:

```
Term t1 = new Term();
Term t2 = new Term();
...

String in = t1.readln(); //use scanner?
```

The point being that each terminal is just another instance of a Java class.  I see many mentions of "the" terminal, but that seems a misnomer.

I realize it's a vague question, I only expect a general answer.  I must be googling with the wrong phrases.

I'm explicitly trying to avoid Swing.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2783206/262852 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2536585/262852

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/972861/262852 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14624965/262852

Comment: this might do it:  http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.ca/2010/09/java-systemconsole-ides-and-testing.html   just looked forever

Comment: well, looks like this is not possible!?  ncurses or jcurses looks to be the way to go.